# How can I move dynamically a gridLine with mouse in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to know,

how can I move a gridLine up/down dynamically with the mouse in d3.js ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done this in the past is to add an extra horizontal or vertical line to your graph and mark it as hidden.

Then whenever an element is moused-over show the line, whenever the element is moused-out hide the line again.  You would need to set the X and Y values of the line such that it matches the location of the element the cursor is hovering over.

This is similar to the way showing/hiding tooltips work: https://gist.github.com/biovisualize/1016860 except you would not use a div (you would use a line) and would not use the location of the mouse pointer (you would use the x and y of the element).